# How do you get social media buttons all the same size?

Tags: javascript, css, facebook-like, social-media

I've come across a few websites where all the social media icons to tweet about that page or like this person or +1 the page on google are all the same size, yet by default they are all different sizes when you grab the code from the relevant website. Here's an example of what I mean by them all being the same size: http://twtvite.com/bedfordtweetup3

Now here's an example of twitter and google side by side by default (click on the click me tab at the top): http://test.fluidstudiosltd.com/

How do people manage to make them the same size? I've been googling this for hours now with no joy. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could copy the buttons javascript to your local server so that you can edit what images are used. I know that you can do that for a couple of services, not sure if it would work for all services.

Keep in mind though, that doing this you run the risk of the javascript being out of date after the sharing services update their local code.

Comment: If this is successful then this would be deployed on a lot of sites. Unfortunately that would just be too much to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to play around with the setting at the relevant button generators as far as I know.

For example, Facebook at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ you select 'box_count' under layout style.

Twitter, see https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button and place 'data-count="vertical"' in relevant place

Hope that's useful. I've spent the last few days researching things like this, and now I'm having really annoying 'error' coming up all the time when I try to like a facebook button. Still, at least I can share what I have found out!

Hope that's useful. I've spent the last few days researching things like this, and now I'm having really annoying 'error' coming up all the time when I try to like a facebook button. Still, at least I can share what I have found out!

Answer (score 0):

Another thing is you can use your own images (just without count boxes) by linking directly, see this link I just spent ages finding again.... http://atlchris.com/1665/how-to-create-custom-share-buttons-for-all-the-popular-social-services/

Have fun!